# Laravel 5.3 Observer not triggering on updating event

Tags: php, laravel-5.3, observers, laravel-events

I have created Observer for my model to update related data:

```
<?php

namespace App\Observers;

use App\User;

class UserObserver
{

public function updating(User $user)
    {
        $data = $user->getAttributes();
        dd($data);
        $user->worker->fill($data['worker']);
        $user->push();
    }
}
```

And add it to my model:

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    parent::observe(UserObserver::class);
}
```

But updating method not firing when updating model:

```
$user = User::byUsername($username)->first();
$user->update($request->all());
```

I have `worker.rate_per_hour` value in request instance and added it to fillable of `User` model.

So my question is, What I am doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like `$object->update($data)` does not fire the `updating` or `updated` events. Try with `$object->prop = 'val'; $object->save()`

Comment: Your decision firing saving event, not updating.

Answer (score 0):

Register the observer in the **AppServiceProvider**:
dir: `/app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`

```php
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        User::observe(UserObserver::class); // here
    }
}
```

Note: Make sure you `cleared cache` & fired `composer dumpauto` command